# Android Studio: new plugin: cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

After Android Studio 2.0 update I started to use new Gradle plugin according to [this article](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental).

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"
```

---

The project build successful and everything is fine, but all lines in `build.gradle` is marked as `cannot resolve symbol xxx`.
[image: build.gradle]

---

Android Studio 2.1 no changes.

---

What is the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem for some time, please let me know if you figure it out, I will too